# Can I re-insert a row with a newly created auto_increment primary key

Tags: mysql

**EDIT:**

I want to update the id to a newly created auto increment id, the rest of the row's columns will not change.

**ORIGINAL:**

I've got a table in mysql looking like:

```
id    userId    productId
```

all columns are UBIGINT, and id is the PRIMARY KEY, set to AUTO INCREMENT.

So now I want to re-insert a row into the same table, but with a newly created id. And the old row should be deleted!

I'm using the id for order (higher == newer).

Is this possible, because the other option is adding a timestamp column and updating this column, but I won't use the timestamp. So I want to prevent this at all costs.

Comment: Yes, it's possible - just insert the new record and delete the old one as you described.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Give an example of old and new row plz.. I think you should try updating, instead of re-insert and your goal would be achieved

Comment: the new row will be the exact same as the old row except it will have a newly generated id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have following table

```
create table so (
    `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
    `num` varchar(20) not null, primary key (`id`),
    unique (`num`)
 ) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

Then we can use following query to insert new row

```
insert into so (num) values ("hi") on duplicate key update id=last_insert_id()+1;
```

If there is already "hi"-row this query will update it's id to be equal next after the last inserted

In your case

```
insert into table (userId, productId) values (someUserId, someProductId)
on duplicate key update id=last_insert_id()+1;
```

Also, there is `replace` MySQL extension.

```
replace into table (userId, productId) values (someUserId, someProductId);
```

As an `on duplicate key update` it will only work if your table has `unique` or `primary key` constraint.
Unlike `on duplicate key update` `replace` will first delete existing row and then insert new, while `on duplicate key update` will just update it.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table (userId, productId) VALUES
(SELECT userId, productId FROM table WHERE id=[id of row]);
DELETE FROM table WHERE id=[id of row];
```

Comment: +1 the OP is probably hoping for a single statement that can do this, but there is no such statement.  This is the solution.  Wrap it in a transaction for atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You just have to delete the old record and add an other one. But you have to know that the auto_increment will always grow.